# Extracting Data from basic object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am using an API that outputs the following object:

```
Object {percentage: 100, status: "Loading Resources", uploading_file: "", event: "progress"}
```

I need to extract the value of the percentage key and assign it to an element in the DOM like so:

```
$("#percentage").text(percentage);
```

The full code that produces this object is:

```
CL3VER.onScriptEvent('progress', function(percentage, status, filename){
    console.log(percentage);
    // $("#percentage").text(percentage);
});
```

How would I extract the percentage data into a variable so I can change the text of a DOM element with JQuery?

Comment: so you have something like var object = {percentage: 100, status: "Loading Resources", uploading_file: "", event: "progress"} right?

Comment: correct, exactly what I have

Comment: I answered take a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you have the object like

```
var object = {percentage: 100, status: "Loading Resources", uploading_file: "", event: "progress"}
```

you could do something like

```
var per = object.percentage;
```

or

```
var per = object["percentage"];
```

then you easily can do something like `$("someselector").text(per);`

Answer (score 0):

what variable holds your object?

if it is `percentage` you can access attributes like you would [any object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```
percentage.percentage
// 100


var yourObj = {percentage: 100, status: "Loading Resources", uploading_file: "", event: "progress"}
yourObj.percentage
// or 
yourObj['percentage']
```